# Emails sent through our application are going to spam or not comming at all

Tags: email-spam

When sending emails through our rails app they are going to spam in some email accounts(hotmail) and not coming at all in others.

We are using sendmail to send the emails. The sender email id is no-reply@xyz.com. What could be the possible reasons for this. Where do we check the logs for the sendmail(ubuntu).

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I think its with your SMTP mail server. if you can send the mail using like Gmail SMTP server you will overcome this prob !

Answer (score 0):

check this list and see if your ip is in the list. Replace your 1.2.3.4 with your ip.
`http://bgp.he.net/ip/1.2.3.4#_rbl`

Answer (score 0):

Check the full headers of the messages that are ending up in spam folders.  The sendmail logs on your end won't tell you anything, unless the recipient's server is refusing your traffic at the SMTP level. Anti-spam software will often add header lines showing which tests failed -- maybe the IP address you're sending from is blacklisted or has a poor reputation; maybe there's something about the content that looks spammy.